# How do the IIS server distinguish from the page expired and the usercontrol expired?

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

Now I set the diference expired time to the Asp.net Web Page outputcache and the Asp.net Web UserControl outputcache. It shows me succee that both of them are updated indenpendency. I think 
that both of these are cached by the IIS server. But Could anyone tell me how do the IIS server
distinguish from the page expired and the usercontrol expired? Do the server judge and combine the cached html content(page html content and the usercontrol html content) by every request?

I hope you could give me some advices. Thank you for your help!
Best Regards,

David Peng

Comment: Hello, I will be very appreciate for you help.